# body background extends into margins or is cut-off when scrolling

Tags: css, layout, background-image

I have a layout where I need to use height: 100% on html and body (and any wrapper divs I resort to using) to achieve an effect similar to pages, so that the content on my first "page" is centred, scrolling down the content on the second "page" is centred etc.

The html looks like this:

```
<section class="page" id="p01">
<div class="spacer">
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Some content
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        Some content
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<section class="page" id="p02">
<div class="spacer">
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Some content
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        Some content
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

and the vertical centring etc. achieved with this styling:

```
body, .page {height: 100%; margin: 0 auto;}

.spacer {
float: left;
height: 50%;
margin-bottom: -150px;
}
.outer {
height: 300px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #fca;
clear: both;
position: relative;
display: block;
white-space: nowrap;
}
.inner {
width: 41%;
margin: 0 6%;
height: 300px;
background-color: green;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
white-space: normal;
}
.inner:first-child {
margin-right: 0;
}
```

You can see it at work in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/terraling/3V5rV/

The problem is the body background (here I'm just using color, but on my site it will be an image) leaks out into the body margins, i.e. the body content has a max-width and should be centred with white margins.

I can fix that either by... setting html background-color to white, as per

http://jsfiddle.net/terraling/yM53t/

...but body background becomes cutoff when scrolling into the second page (that wasn't a problem in the first fiddle).

Alternatively I could set the background image on a wrapper div and not on the body. That solves the problem of it leaking into the body margins, but it still has the same problem that it is cut off on scrolling.

(see: http://jsfiddle.net/terraling/3V5rV/1/ )

Any solution that involves removing the height: 100% declaration from any of html, body or wrapper collapses the layout (including replacing with max-height: 100%).

Comment: Before giving an solution: Why does the spacer float and have a negative margin? Can we change that?

Comment: The spacer is there to vertically centre .outer within the section, ie to centre it on the screen. The negative bottom margin is half the height of .outer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a whole lot of problems with this construct and not all of them can be solved, unfortunately.

### The background issue

As you have seen yourself the background of `body` extends to the viewport if `html` does not have a background. That's solvable.

### The float issue

When an element floats it does not contribute to the height of its parent element. So they don't grow (e.g. body does not expand). That can be solved if you can use alternatives. For vertically centering an element you could use `display: table-cell` e.g., which allows you to vertically center the content.

### The height issue

This is where all hope is gone. `height: 100%` refers to the height of the parent, of course. The parent of `body` is `html` which in turn is the child of the viewport. You gave `html` the size of `100%` (= the size of the viewport) and `body` the size of `100%` (= size of `html` = size of viewport).

So now `body` has a fixed height and it can't expand meaning the background doesn't expand as well. Now one might have the idea to give `body` no size so that it can expand. But `.page` has `100%` too. If a parent (in this case `body`) has no fixed size `100%` has no meaning and will be treated as `auto`, which means as big as the content. And the content has a height of `300px`. So the `.page` elements wouild no longer have the height of the viewport but `300px`.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question with such clarity - albeit in the negative!

Answer (score 0):

As for the collapse of the CSS, you should either specify the height specifically `height:200px;` or add padding to the bottom/top of the page so that the content wraps. You can also use `min-height:200px;` then add the `margin-bottom:20px;` to separate the pages. I would approach this at a specific height with the wrapper having the specific `background-image` and `bottom-margin`.

In order to center your background-image to the `<html>` you can specify the position as 50%.
This can be done by doing `background:url('yourimage.jpg') repeat 0 50%;`This will ensure the background is centered.

Comment: Thanks for answering meeb0, but if I've understood you correctly, what you are suggesting requires me to know the height of the browser viewport to centre the content, and that means resorting to javascript, which I may have to do, but it means coming up with a fallback for when javascript is unavailable.

Comment: Are you trying to center the content in the middle of the page vertically and horizontally? I was trying to understand the point of this? You can either work in %'s and/or em's for font to follow the basis or a proportionate grid, padding to wrap around the content and margins up to ie8 then below that it gets a bit crappy!

Comment: try this to get you started and you can use jquery pretty easily if you really need center. Unfortunately you are limited. Chris coyier's site is quite good. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/exactly-center-an-imagediv-horizontally-and-vertically/